# Android studio 4.1 - How to disable Run the Android Emulator directly in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-4.1

**[Android studio 4.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#4-1-0)**

Run the Android Emulator directly in Android Studio is new release change in **android studio** but some time I need ***disable*** that how to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There will be an option as you can see in the below picture:

[image]

Comment: "Uncheck" the box then click "OK" then "Close" Android Studio an open it again then the emulator will be appear as a standalone application.